# Trying to find DBZ theme

Tags: music, dragon-ball-z

It plays on episode 24 at 9:00, been trying to find it for the past half hour and can't maybe someone can help me?

It should be from the original OST (japanese)

Comment: I watched that episode, didn't hear anything at 9:00..

Answer (score -1):

The soundtrack which was played for first 199 episodes in DGZ was Cha-La Head-Ha-La by Hironobu Kageyama. Just check. if this is the one you are searching for. The link is right below.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Hironobu_Kageyama_-_Cha-La_Head-Cha-La.ogg